# How do I use Prometheus irate function

Tags: prometheus

Noob question from my side about irate. Im tracking method calls with an aspect. I'm executing method exactly once. When I'm scraping every 5s i get value 0.2. when every 10s i get 0.1. Why? As far as I can understood irate,  in both cases most recent data points differ exactly the same way (by this +1 method call)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One increase over 5 seconds is 0.2, one increase over 10 seconds is 0.1. Both average to 0.1 over 10 seconds.